# nginx: break in location block not preventing redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, nginx-location

With the following config, I am sending a post request to `http://192.168.0.101:8001/A/`.  The second `location` block hits, and the URL, as it appears on the browser, is changed to `http://192.168.0.101:8001/foo/`.  This results in a redirect, and the first `location` block hits.  My expectation is that since I have a `break` in the `rewrite`, there will be no more redirects.  However, I get a "192.168.0.101 redirected you too many times." error because it seems that a redirect is happening again to the second `location` block.  This results in an infinite loop.

```
location /foo {
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    rewrite ^/foo/(.*) /A$1 break;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/mysite.sock;
}

location ~ ^/A/(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://192.168.0.101:8001/foo/$1;
}
```

Why is there another redirect happening even though I have a `break`?  I've confirmed the first `location` block is hitting because if I change the `rewrite` inside there to `rewrite ^/foo/(.*) /AA$1 break;`, I get a "The requested URL /AA was not found on this server." error, as expected.

Comment: `break` works within one request. You have two separate requests, because `return 301` doing external redirect.

Comment: The `break` is working, the 2nd redirect is coming from the app. Do you intend to rewrite `/foo/xxx` to `/Axxx` or `/A/xxx`? Maybe you are missing a `/`.

Comment: This question is partially related to my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538531/change-publicly-visible-url-and-but-keep-url-same-internally).  If I do just ```rewrite /foo/xxx```, the redirect happens internally.  I want the externally visible URL to also change.  When you say the '2nd redirect is coming from the app,' are you referring nginx?

Comment: I understand the redirect as a result of the ```return``` results in another request, but that request should only hit the first location block.  Shouldn't the ```break``` prevent further redirects?